# Unable to install eUML2 free edition for eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I put the url in my update manager in eclipse. I got an error -

```
Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could not be found.
Software being installed: eDepend 3.7.1.20110624 (com.soyatec.edepend.feature.
group 3.7.1.20110624)
Missing requirement: eDepend 3.7.1.20110624 (com.soyatec.edepend.feature.group 
3.7.1.20110624) requires 'org.eclipse.platform.feature.group 
[3.3.0.v20070608-_19UEkLF-XsdF9jJrkPi,4.0.0)' but it could not be found
```

I searched google, but found nothing. How do I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use the right version?

Requirements can be found here >>
[eUML2 installation requirements](http://www.soyatec.com/euml2/installation/)

(p.s. i used the local installation, that worked for me)

Answer (score -2):

Install the "Graphical Modelling Framework (GMF) Runtime" first,  restart Eclipse and install eUML2.